# The term 'connect-QADService' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet... inside C# function

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory, powershell-cmdlet

Can someone, please, help to understand why the following code inside a Csharp function

```
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    runspace.Open();
    Pipeline pipe = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    Command connectToActDir = new Command("connect-QADService");
    connectToActDir.Parameters.Add("Service", "'ip:port'");
    connectToActDir.Parameters.Add("ConnectionAccount", "'user.local\administrator'");
    connectToActDir.Parameters.Add("ConnectionPassword", "'password'");
    pipe.Commands.Add(connectToActDir);
    pipe.Invoke();
```

causes the following error

**The term 'connect-QADService' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**

while ActiveRoles cmdlets are installed and running the equivalent command in power shell succeeds. Do I miss some dll in project references?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Quest ActiveRoles cmdlets are not loaded into a PowerShell session by default, because they're not part of PowerShell.

PowerShell 3 will automatically load modules when needed. I don't know if this holds true when using a RunSpace as I've never used PowerShell this way.

Do you load the Quest snap-in or module in your PowerShell profile? You'll need to do the equivalent in your C# code.